# JQuery: Catch POST Array before submitting?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, submit

is it possible to catch the POST Array using JQuery before submitting the form?
I know I could use `preventDefault()` and read all the variables, but that´s not what i want. I have to get the POST Array before to send it via AJAX to a php file.

Comment: you want to capture them before calling ajax??

Comment: Yes I want to post them with AJAX so i could simulate a real post submit.

Comment: The answer shud be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `preventDefault()`, `serializeArray()` will do what you want:

```
$( '#yourFormID' ).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var postarray = $("#yourFormID").serializeArray();
    //do what ever you want with "postarray"

    //for example send it via POST
    $.post( "yourfile.php", postarray, function( data ) {
         //handle here the response
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that will help me :)

Answer (score 0):

For `$.ajax`, when value of property `type:` is `POST` you are sending data using post method. So there's nothing complicated to collect `$_POST` global arrays data. All data you are sending using `type:'POST'` for `$.ajax` and `$.post` are POST data and will be collected by `$_POST` global array.

Comment: That´s not what i wanted. With your solution I have to select all inputs manually.